# Integer variable not following while loop conditions

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, while-loop, int

I've been having an issue with my code concerning arrays and int variables. In the section that I have issues with, I'm trying to check if an array (in which the user inputs their own integers) is in an increasing order, and if it is in an increasing order, the array is printed; if not, an error message is displayed. I am trying to do this using int two variables, one called c1 and another called orderCheck1 (both initialized to 0).

```
int[ ] list1 = new int [10000];

int a1 =0;
int b1 =0;
int c1 =0;
int value1;
int orderCheck1 =0;

while (a1 ==0){
  if (b1 < list1.length){
    value1 = scan.nextInt();
    //checks to see if value entered is positive
    if (value1 >=0){
      list1[b1] = value1;
      b1++;
    }
    else{
      a1 =1;
    }
  }
}

while (c1 <(list1.length-1)){
  if (list1[c1] >list1[(c1+1)]){
    orderCheck1 =1;
  }
  c1++;
}

if (orderCheck1 ==0){
  for (int i =0; i < b1; i++){
    System.out.print (list1[i] + " ");
  }
}
else{
  System.out.println ("ERROR: One or both arrays are not in an increasing order.);
}
```

Basically, if a number in the array is larger than the number following it, orderCheck will become 1. Later in the code, it checks if orderCheck1 is either zero or one. If orderCheck1 is zero, then the ints in the array are printed; if it is one, then the error message is displayed.
The issue is, no matter what I enter, orderCheck1 always becomes a one, so the error message is always printed. What is wrong with my code?

Note: When the user enters values into the array, they are supposed to enter a negative number to stop entering values.

Comment: What do you see when you step through the code with a debugger? Are you sure you aren't storing that ending `-1`?

Comment: What array are you supplying as input and how are you reading that input ?

Comment: What is `b1`?  If `b1` could be less than `list1.length`, then does that mean your `while` loop is checking data that isn't really in the array?

Comment: Yeah I'm sure. I tried to print the thing without the order check, and no negative value is included.

Comment: If the comments haven't helped you figure out the problem, you'll need to show us more code.  Please see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) information about creating minimal, complete, verifiable examples.

Comment: You should add `break` after `orderCheck1 = 1;`. Also if you are entering the last negative number into the array then the while condition should be `while(c1 <(list1.length-2))`. You have to initialize `ordercheck` to `0` before the loop.

Comment: Hmm, it still prints out my error message...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem, I believe, is that you've allocated a list of 10000 elements, and you don't use them all.  Java initializes the elements to 0.  (Note that in some other languages, a construct like this could initialize the elements to random garbage values.)

You then write a loop that inputs numbers until the user enters a negative number.  This will set the first *n* elements of the loop for some number *n*.  But the remaining elements do not get chopped off the array.  They are still there, and they are still 0.

This causes a problem for this loop:

```
while (c1 <(list1.length-1)){
  if (list1[c1] >list1[(c1+1)]){
    orderCheck1 =1;
  }
  c1++;
}
```

Note that `list1.length` is still 10000, even though the user didn't enter 10000 values.  Once an array is created with `new int[10000]` or something like that, that fixes the `.length` of the array.  This length cannot be changed.  That means `c1` will go up to 9999, regardless of how many values were entered.

Therefore, at some point, you will hit a point where you start comparing to the 0 values that got put in the array when you created it.  Since all the values the user entered are positive, that means `list1[c1] > list1[c1+1]` will be true when `list[c1]` is the last value entered, because `list1[c1+1]` will still be 0.

The solution is that instead of letting `c1` go up to `list1.length-1`, you have to stop it when it gets to, I think, one less than the number of user entries.  It looks like you already have a `b1` that counts the number of entries, so the `while` needs to be changed to `while (c1 <`*some-expression-that-uses-b1*`)`.  I'll let you work on getting that upper limit right.

**One more thing:** When you have an array like this whose size isn't really known, it's better to use an [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).  Unlike an `int[]`, an `ArrayList<Integer>` will grow as you add elements to it, and the `size()` method will return the actual number of elements added.

Comment: Okay thanks! I'll try this out and get back to you on that. The reason I set the array length to 10000 is because my AP teacher told us to do that, since we haven't learned the arraylist yet.

Comment: So instead of list1.length, I tried using  `while(c1 <(b1-1))` and it worked! Now I know that empty elements are initialized to 0.  Thanks a lot @ajb

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a method:

```
static boolean isAscending(int[] nums) {
    for (int i = 1; i < nums.length; i++)
        if (nums[i - 1] > nums[i])
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

Note that this handles the edge case of arrays of size zero or one correctly.

Comment: What you haven't done is tell him what he should pass as a parameter.  The only `int[]` he has is an array whose length is 10000.